# Does the following code imply that the implementations of the methods are supplied as dlls only without C# source code?

Tags: c#, .net, http

In the C# code that I am reading, there are calls to `WinHttpConnect` and other methods.

I guessed they were implemented based on methods in .Net Framework Class Libraries in `System.Net`, such as WebClient, WebRequest, WebResponse, or HttpClient. I want to verify my guess, so use Visual Studio 2015 IDE to find where they are defined and implemented. But I didn't find where the methods are implemented, but reached the following code in a .cs file at the end.

1. Does the following code imply that the implementations of the
   methods are supplied as dlls only without C# source code?
2. Are the methods from some libraries?

   - Are there documentations about
     the usage of the methods?
   - Were the libraries written in C# too?
   - Which are better for programmers to use, the libraries where the methods come from, or the .Net Framework Class Libraries under `System.Net`?

Thanks.

```
private class NativeMethods
{


    #region Private Constants
    private const string DllName = "WinHttp";
    #endregion

    #region Native Windows Class
    private static class NativeApi
    {
        [DllImport(DllName, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "WinHttpAddRequestHeaders", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(IntPtr requestHandle, string headers, int headersLength, uint modifiers);

        [DllImport(DllName, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "WinHttpCloseHandle", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WinHttpCloseHandle(IntPtr internetHandle);

        [DllImport(DllName, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "WinHttpConnect", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern IntPtr WinHttpConnect(IntPtr sessionHandle, string serverName, ushort serverPort, uint reserved);

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[DllImport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) is a special attribute in C# that defines a function to use in C# that is implemented in an unmanaged DLL file.

In this case, the DLL file is called `winhttp.dll` and you can find it in your `C:\Windows\System32` folder. This DLL file is an unmanaged DLL file (meaning it was written using a native, non-.NET language, such as C or C++) that is shipped with the Windows operating system.

You can find documentation about [WinHttpAddRequestHeaders here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384087(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WinHttpCloseHandle here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384090(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WinHttpConnect here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384091(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you are writing a program in a .NET language and there are .NET wrappers available, it is always wiser to use those. If there are no .NET wrappers for the functions you need to invoke, then you must use `DllImport` to import the function into C#. Then you can write your own .NET wrappers (which is essentially what Microsoft did with these 3 functions).

Also, if you need to use an unmanaged DLL in your application but you are unsure of how to declare the [DllImport] attribute, there is a site called [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/) which has a list of a lot of common unmanaged DLL files and provides you with the correct [DllImport] method.

Since `WinHttp.Dll` is part of the Windows Operating System and Windows source code is proprietary, you probably won't be able to find it's source code. However, if you really want to "get an idea" of how it works under the hood, [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) is a program for Linux that allows Linux to run Windows application. It does this by emulating the underlying system DLL files. Wine is open source and you can see the source code for how they [implemented WinHttp.dll](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/tree/master/dlls/winhttp). Keep in mind this is NOT Microsoft code though and Wine might implement the DLL a little bit different. But it should give you an idea about what's going on.